# Error when using optional tuple as function result in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In one of my modules I use an optional tuple for a function result:

```
function ruleFromPosition(position): [string, number] | undefined;
```

and assign this to local vars in my unit tests:

```
let [ruleName, ruleIndex] = ruleFromPosition(position);
```

This results in the error:

> Type must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

I could re-write this statement as:

```
let [ruleName, ruleIndex] = ruleFromPosition(position)!;
```

, which compiles, but that disallows for nullable checks. What's the correct way to use the tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a TypeScript "problem". You just can't destructure *undefined*:

```
let [a, b,] = undefined;
```

> BOOM: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

(see [exploringjs, destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#_array-patterns-work-with-iterables))

Since your function has the propability of returning *undefined*, TypeScript won't compile. You can:

#### Check for the return value

```
function ruleFromPosition(position): [string, number] | undefined {
    if (position > 1) return undefined;

    return ['1', 0];
}

const result = ruleFromPosition(1);

if (result) {
  let [ruleName, ruleIndex] = result;
}
```

#### Return an destructurable array

```
function ruleFromPosition(position): [string | undefined, number | undefined] {
    if (position > 1) return [undefined, undefined];

    return ['1', 0];
}

let [ruleName, ruleIndex] = ruleFromPosition(0);
```

Comment: The second solution has the disadvantage of allowing that one tuple member is undefined and the other is not. That's why I like the first variant more, even though it means slightly more code. Thanks.